# Email selection screen, set default recipient email

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have an easy one, never had to do it before
I'm on the invoice, I click on the + and I click on email.
The recipient email is the customer, fine.
But I have a case where I need to hardcode the email.
I created a workflow and assign the email to the hardcoded address.
It's not working and I'm not surprised.
I want to update the email recipient field in the "popup" screen

I'm sure it's easy for all of you but it would help me

Mark

Comment: _"t's not working"_ is not a problem description. Why not? And if you want help with code, you should post the code. This is currently a very vague question with little scope for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The logic needs to be deployed to the message record instead of the invoice record. I am not sure if the message record is exposed to workflows, but it is exposed to user event scripts. A user event script deployed on the message record will execute on every message, so the script logic needs to check the passed parameters to determine if the email was opened from an invoice. The easiest way to change the recipient email address is to use a redirect with the desired parameters.